# "The solution would be that he go and talk."

Tags: verbs, nouns, grammatical-number, tenses, present-tense

Just need to confirm if this construction is correct.

Would also really appreciate it if it could be broken down too from a grammatical perspective.

Many thanks!

Comment: It looks to be kind of missing something at the end.  *... and talk to his doctor*, for example, would seem like a more complete sentence.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yeah it was just an example sentence. My actual question was - is saying "go and talk" fine here, or should be it be "goes and talk"?